# count total hash collisions in template class c++

Tags: c++, templates, hash

Created a template class that hashes a string into an integer from 0 - 999 3 different ways. I am trying to compare the hashed value and the index value, and when they are different adding to a count and then return that number for a total number of collisions. My question is if I am doing this correctly, because I was just guessing when I threw this all together.

code:

```
#include <string>

#include <list>

template<typename T>
class Hash
{
protected:

    // Capacity of the hash table
    static const size_t SIZE = 1000;

    // Defines an entry in the hash table
    class Entry
    {
    public:
        std::string key;
        T value;
        bool used;
        Entry()
        {
            used = false;
            value = T();
        }
    };

    // The hash table entries
    Entry entries[SIZE];

    // Hash function #1
    size_t hash1(const std::string& k) const;

    // Hash function #2
    size_t hash2(const std::string& k) const;

    // Hash function #3
    size_t hash3(const std::string& k) const;

    // Calculate the hash of a given key
    //  TODO: change this to use the desired hash function
    size_t hash(const std::string& k) const
    {
        return hash1(k);
    }

    // Perform linear probing on the given key and index to get index
    size_t probe(const std::string& k, size_t i) const;
public:
    // Access data item in hash for the given key
    T& operator[](const std::string& k);

    void print() const
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            std::cout << i << "-" << entries[i].used << "-" << entries[i].key
                    << "-" << entries[i].value << std::endl;
    }
    size_t collision(const std::string& k) const;
};

template<typename T>
size_t Hash<T>::hash1(const std::string& k) const
{
    int index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k.size(); i++)
        index += k[i];
    return index % SIZE;
}

template<typename T>
size_t Hash<T>::hash2(const std::string& k) const
{
    int index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k.size(); i++)
    {
        index += (k[i] + 27 * k[i] + 729 * k[i]);
    }
    return index % SIZE;
}

template<typename T>
size_t Hash<T>::hash3(const std::string& k) const
{
    int index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k.size(); i++)
    {
        index += 37 * index + k[i];
    }
    return index % SIZE;
}

template<typename T>
size_t Hash<T>::probe(const std::string& k, size_t i) const
{
    int index = i;
    int count = 0;
    while (entries[index].used && entries[index].key != k && count < SIZE)
        index = (index + 1) % SIZE;
    return index;
}

template<typename T>
T& Hash<T>::operator[](const std::string& k)
{
    int index = hash(k);
    if (entries[index].used && entries[index].key != k)
        index = probe(k, index);
    if (!entries[index].used)
    {
        entries[index].key = k;
        entries[index].used = true;
    }
    return entries[index].value;
}

template<typename T>
size_t Hash<T>::collision(const std::string& k) const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (j == entries[j].value)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Since the size of the list is a constant 1000, the index values are always 0 to 999. Knowing this, if i compare that number to the hashed value (entries[j].value) and they are the same then I know that the values are the same and there was a collision, so i can then add to the count.

I am trying it this way because my professor stated "You can
determine this by examining each entry in the hash table and comparing the stored key value’s hash value to the index within the table." and truthfully I'm not sure what he means by that. I'm going to apologize in advance because I have a strong feeling this is completely wrong.

Comment: I think he meant to compare `index == hash(entries[index].key)`

Comment: What you describe sounds good to me. The hash of the key tells you where in the table your value should go. If the value is not in the table at the location suggested by the hash of the key, you have had a collision. Your code makes two mistakes that I see: 1. it doesn't take into account that a location in the table might be unused. 2. it doesn't compute the hash of the key

Comment: Actually, third mistake? Why pass in `k`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The hash of the key tells you where in the table your value should go. If the value is not in the table at the location suggested by the hash of the key, you have had a collision.

Your code makes two mistakes counting collisions that I see: 1. it doesn't take into account that a location in the table might be unused. 2. it doesn't compute and test against the hash of the key.

```
template<typename T>
size_t Hash<T>::collision() const // doesn't seem to be any reason to pass in a key
{
    size_t count = 0; // returning size_t, might as well use size_t
                      // negative collisions isn't a possibility anyway
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) // compare like datatypes where possible
    {
        if (entries[j].used) // can't be a collision if the location is empty
        {
            size_t index = hash(entries[j].key); // get correct index for key
            if (j != index) // increment count if in wrong slot in table
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: ugh thank you! idk why i didn't think of that, it makes so much more sense than what I was trying to do. You're a lifesaver. :)